# How to read TextBox values without conversion in VC++

Tags: visual-studio-2013, c++-cli

I've built a form with Visual Studio 2013 and I'm using C++.
My goal is to read the values from a textbox and write them to a binary file.

The problem I face is that when I input a hex value it is still converted to hex and I would like to write it without conversion.

```
        Char id1= Convert::ToByte(textBox1->Text);
        UInt16 id2= Convert::ToInt16(textBox2->Text);
        UInt32 id3= Convert::ToInt32(textBox3->Text);

        String^ fileName = "id.id";

        FileStream^ fileStr = gcnew FileStream(fileName, FileMode::Append);
        BinaryWriter^ binwr = gcnew BinaryWriter(fileStr);

        binwr->Write(id1);
        binwr->Write(id2);
        binwr->Write(id3);

        fileStr->Close();
        binwr->Close();
```

So if I input 8041 I would like to have in the binary file 8041 not 1f08.

Thanks

Comment: So use the two-argument function to specify a base? See e.g. [this `ToInt32` reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k20k614(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1).

Comment: The debugger will gladly show you the values of  `id1`, `id2` and `id3` if you put a breakpoint at the appropriate location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Some programmer dude 's comment

```
UInt16 id2= Convert::ToInt16(textBox2->Text, 16);
```

is the right answer.

Thank you @Some programmer dude !

Comment: You can mark your own answer as answer to help others.

Comment: I am allowed to do this tomorrow (48 hours after answering your own question) and I will do so. Thank you.